# Chrome extension - load content script on URL updates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having this problem where I want to run a content script `content.js` on pages with URLs matching `https://www.example.com/*`. I have defined in `manifest.json` the following:

```
{ 
  ...

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],

  ...
}
```

However, `content.js` will not be loaded when the user navigates from another page (say `https://www.foo.bar`) to `https://www.example.com/*`, for example by clicking a hyperlink. It's only loaded when the user directly visits `https://www.example.com/*`.

I'm considering injecting `content.js` into all pages, and listening for `chrome.tabs.onUpdate` in the background to see if the current URL matches `https://www.example.com/*`, and depending on that send messages to `content.js`. Is there a better way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject your script programmatically from the background page, making the function where you are to send/receive messages executeScript's callback:

```
function processUrl(tabId, url) {
  if(url.indexOf("https://www.example.com")>-1){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"content.js"}, function() {
      //send and receive msgs  here
    };
  }
}
```

Then just call this function from your listener(s). If you want to use a library or other dependency, call executeScript with the library first, and executeScript with your script in the first call's callback.